# Where are the Sign-In logs for Azure VMs when using Azure AD credentials?

Tags: logging, azure-active-directory

I don't find them in the expected location in the Portal:  Azure AD > Users > Sign-In Logs.

I've had multiple tickets opened in Azure, they get bounced around from group to group until they simply stop responding.  I just opened another ticket with guidance from my Azure Customer Success Manager, and the first response is that they are transferring the ticket.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Per

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this scenario on my end and got the VM Event logs successfully, Refer here:-

[image]

I have created a VM with Azure AD login and logged in with the Azure AD user inside the VM.

> Azure cannot capture the logs inside the VM directly, In-order to see the logs of the Azure AD user log in you need to find it inside the VM’s Event viewer data plane.

You need to find it here> Search for Event viewer > TerminalServices>LocalSessionManager>Operational and select the logs like below:-

[image]

But you can send these Event Logs to Azure Log analytics workspace and then get insights or query.
In-order to connect your VM’s event Logs to Log Analytics workspace >

*Log in to Azure Portal from your VM with the same azure ad user > Select your log analytics workspace > Legacy agents management > add your event logs like below* :-

[image]

And click on Apply **Note- the above pane uses legacy agent management which will be deprecated in 2024, Its recommended to migrate to MMA and create data collection resource.**

For that you need to download log analytics agent inside your VM OS and configure the Log analytics workspace ID like below :-

[image]

Open the downloaded agent and install it in your VM and select Next > I agree > Connect the Agent to Log analytics (OMS)

[image]

Select Next and then copy your LA workspace ID and primary key from above like below and install the Microsoft Monitoring agent inside your VM :-

[image]

Create Data collection endpoint for the VM event logs :-

[image]

[image]

Also, Add the Data source with your VM event logs :-

[image]

[image]

To capture your VM logs in Azure Monitor, **I got the VM Event Logs successfully like below** :-

[image]

You can also connect your VM to LA workspace like below :-

[image]

[image]

And see the VM related logs.

You can also make use of Diagnostics settings in from Azure Portal VM pane to get additional logs :-

[image]

Reference :-

[Collect Windows event log data sources with Log Analytics agent in Azure Monitor - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-windows-events)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Siddhesh.  Kudo's on the level of detail as well!

Comment: What I was hoping for was to be able to collect login events from a central place, like Azure Active Directory.  It seems odd, and somewhat backwards, to pull logging from each server when all the information is presented to the Authentication Authority.  I will mark this answer as complete because it does deliver the goods. I will also update the thread as well, if Microsoft ever gives a clear answer about whether AAD can deliver this.

Comment: As you have enabled Azure AD Login, the Sign in users will be visible in the Sign-In Logs page of your Azure AD refer here - [signin](https://i.imgur.com/gW3NLyc.png) , [store and send signin logs to LA](https://i.imgur.com/w2ScIAG.png)  You can also directly enable the Monitoring agent inside your VM by clicking here -[Enable monitoring agent](https://i.imgur.com/4j9M2aZ.png) , This will automatically install Microsoft Monitoring Agent in your VM.

Comment: I have viewed the Sign-In logs but the events from AAD Users to Azure VM's are not present there.  There are logs labeled "Managed Identity Sign-Ins" that identify the server event but not the User.  It likely is possible to cobble together a manually intensive report by correlating these logs with the Events from Linux log and Windows Events, but I'm confused why AAD cant report these elements together.  I've not even found a MS Support Agent that says, "Yea, we don't do that".  They keep insisting they do and then transferring the ticket(s).

Comment: AFAIK, VM RDP operation is a data plane level task, So Azure AD does not support centralized logging for the same, For now you can enable Azure monitor or Log analytics